# Change field date to date-time field with already data in table

Tags: drupal, content-type

On a drupal site we added the date/time field.

First we needed only the day, month , year notation.
Now we also need the hours and minutes. But there is already some data in the table.
Now you can't change the field settings.

What's a good solution, where we don't lose the already existing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by doing the following.

Export the table ....._startdate.
Make that same table empty
Change the fieldsetting to the right format.
Import the exported data back into table ....._startdate.

And it works perfectly. :)